# Will adding Python to a machine with LibreOffice interfere with LibreOffice Python macro execution?

Tags: python, macros, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice installed on a Windows machine.  LibreOffice comes with a bundled python.exe (version 3.3) to allow you to write LibreOffice macros in Python.  This works fine.  But the bundled python routines don't come with the IDLE python ide as far as I can see.

1) If I download and install Python on my machine will that interfere with the execution of LibreOffice python macros (by changing Python environmental variables, register settings etc.?

or

2) Is there a way to download IDLE or another free Python IDE and have it work with the Python bundled into LibreOffice?

Comment: Do you want to use IDLE to develop LibreOffice macros? If not, just download and install a Python and use it and its IDLE separately -- the two shouldn't interfere with one another.

Comment: I want it to help debug LibreOffice macros. I want access to "REPL" in an IDE.

Comment: You may be able to write your own REPL using one of the [Interpreter base classes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html?highlight=interactiveinterpreter#module-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing a separate copy of Python (from, for example, [python.org](http://python.org/download)), will not interfere with copies of Python bundled with other programs (LibreOffice, Sublime Text, Blender, Anaconda, etc.). They are installed in separate directories, and in general use separate environment variables.

I'm not that familiar with the LibreOffice version of Python, but you don't need IDLE to write Python programs - any text editor will do, although I have a personal preference for [Sublime](http://sublimetext.com). I would assume that Libre has functionality like the Python interactive interpreter for iterative development and testing; check the docs for details.

Comment: There is no interactive interpreter with the bundled Python.  I.e. no idle.py

Comment: @HarrySpier I meant interactive interpreter as in what you get when you run `python` from the command line. There's no option in Libre to enter arbitary Python commands and have them evaluated? That stinks...

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless LibreOffice was programmed sloppy, it should not
2. That would not be smart: using bundled software for anything else than what it was bundled for would not be smart

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice comes bundled with it's own copy of python. (Python 3.3 I think)
So the answer to your question is no, it will not.
I have found that a simple way of debugging python macros in libreoffice is to run libreoffice from the command line and put print commands in the macros. This at least allows you to trace where you are and what key values are as the print commands echo onto the terminal screen.